# Unable to launch appium configuration on iphone from Xcode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

We are trying to launch a WebDriverAgent and its getting stuck at the following step (Extract of log):

```
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command 'security -v unlock-keychain -p   exited with code 49
```

The app is getting installed on the phone.The error is only while attempting to launch from Xcode and works fine when run directly from the phone.

**Code:**

public void setup() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {        System.out.println("====Setting capabilities====");         DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();        // cap.setCapability("appium-version", "1.6.4");        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "10.3");       // cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");         cap.setCapability("deviceName", "astha’s iPhone");      cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");       cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");        cap.setCapability("showXcodeLog", "true");      cap.setCapability("udid", "86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260");      //cap.setCapability("desiredCapabilities", "optional");         // cap.setCapability("udid","80072f1273b0ac59431f70934d9d5eec38de8a3a");

```
    cap.setCapability("keychainPath", "/Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12");      //cap.setCapability("keychainPath", "/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Keychains/MyKeychain.keychain");
            cap.setCapability("keychainPassword", "<password>");        /// Users/atulmhetre/Library/Keychains/         //// Users/atulmhetre/Documents/MyPrivateKey.p12        File app = new File("/Users/atulmhetre/Desktop/Sample Application/UiKitCatalog.app");       cap.setCapability("app",
            "/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app");      // cap.setCapability("app","/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UIKitCatalog-akevtpkxonmoyogdvhqvrqlkacji/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UIKitCatalog.app");

    cap.setCapability("bundleId", "com.nihilent.IntegrationApp");       // cap.setCapability("bundleId","com.example.nihilent.UIKitCatalogMob");

    cap.setCapability("noReset", true);         System.out.println("====after setting====");        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);       driver.findElementByName("Alerts").click();
```

**Appium Logs:**

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.4 [Appium] Non-default server args: [Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1 [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723 [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app","showXcodeLog":"true","noReset":true,"platformVersion":"10.3","automationName":"XCUITest","keychainPath":"/Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12","bundleId":"com.nihilent.IntegrationApp","keychainPassword":"republic123","platformName":"iOS","udid":"86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260","deviceName":"astha’s iPhone"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app","showXcodeLog":"true","noReset":true,"platformVersion":"10.3","automationName":"XCUITest","keychainPath":"/Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12","bundleId":"com.nihilent.IntegrationApp","keychainPassword":"republic123","platformName":"iOS","udid":"86c8805d20315df3c4 [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app","showXcodeLog":"true","noReset":true,"platformVersion":"10.3","automationName":"XCUITest","keychainPath":"/Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12","bundleId":"com.nihilent.IntegrationApp","keychainPassword":"republic123","platformName":"iOS","udid":"86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260","deviceName":"astha’s iPhone"},{},{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app","showXcodeLog":"true","noReset":true,"platformVersion":"10.3","automationName":"XCUITest","keychainPath":"/Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12","bundleId":"com.nihilent.IntegrationApp","keychainPassword":"republic123","platformName":"iOS","udid":"86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260","deviceName":"astha’s iPhone"},"requiredCapabilities":{},... [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1494757197935 (15:49:57 GMT+0530 (IST)) [Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.27.2) session [Appium] Capabilities: [Appium]   app: '/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app' [Appium]   showXcodeLog: 'true' [Appium]   noReset: true [Appium]   platformVersion: '10.3' [Appium]   automationName: 'XCUITest' [Appium]   keychainPath: '/Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12' [Appium]   bundleId: 'com.nihilent.IntegrationApp' [Appium]   keychainPassword: 'republic123' [Appium]   platformName: 'iOS' [Appium]   udid: '86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260' [Appium]   deviceName: 'astha’s iPhone' [XCUITest] XCUITestDriver version: 2.27.2 [BaseDriver] Capability 'showXcodeLog' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 8ffef180-184b-436c-8648-e4af5805b9d4 [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '8.3.2' (tools v8.1.0.0.1.1476494586) [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '10.3' [BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1494757198121 (15:49:58 GMT+0530 (IST)) [XCUITest] Available devices: 86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260 [XCUITest] Creating iDevice object with udid '86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260' [XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260', real device: true [BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app' [BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1494757198383 (15:49:58 GMT+0530 (IST)) [XCUITest] Checking whether app '/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app' is actually present on file system [XCUITest] App is present [BaseDriver] Event 'resetStarted' logged at 1494757198385 (15:49:58 GMT+0530 (IST)) [XCUITest] Reset: fullReset not set. Leaving as is [BaseDriver] Event 'resetComplete' logged at 1494757198386 (15:49:58 GMT+0530 (IST)) [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog [iOSLog] Found idevicesyslog: '/usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog' [BaseDriver] Event 'logCaptureStarted' logged at 1494757198552 (15:49:58 GMT+0530 (IST)) [XCUITest] Setting up real device [XCUITest] Installing '/Users/atulmhetre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app' on device with UUID '86c8805d20315df3c4f707e25ee4327a12106260'... [XCUITest] The app has been installed successfully. [BaseDriver] Event 'appInstalled' logged at 1494757201209 (15:50:01 GMT+0530 (IST)) [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1494757201211 (15:50:01 GMT+0530 (IST)) [XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent' [XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj' [XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device [XCUITest] Carthage found: '/usr/local/bin/carthage' [XCUITest] Killing hanging processes [XCUITest] Setting security for iOS device [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1494757201483 (15:50:01 GMT+0530 (IST))
**[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command 'security -v unlock-keychain -p republic123 /Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12' exited with code 49** [XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying [XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes [XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1494757211928 (15:50:11 GMT+0530 (IST)) [XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent' [XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj' [XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device [XCUITest] Carthage found: '/usr/local/bin/carthage' [XCUITest] Killing hanging processes [XCUITest] Setting security for iOS device [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1494757212093 (15:50:12 GMT+0530 (IST))
**[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command 'security -v unlock-keychain -p republic123 /Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12' exited with code 49** [XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying [XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes [XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device [**XCUITest] Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command 'security -v unlock-keychain -p republic123 /Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12' exited with code 49**
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:374:15)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)  Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command 'security -v unlock-keychain -p republic123 /Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12' exited with code 49
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:374:15)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7) [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on. [iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: Command 'security -v unlock-keychain -p republic123 /Users/atulmhetre/Documents/Certificates.p12' exited with code 49
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:374:15)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7) [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 24471 ms - 317

Appreciate your responses in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: @JeffC Thank you for pointing out. Required information have been added.